# Redux combineReducers not passing state to reducer

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

In the following code, data `(state, action)` is not being passed to the reducers by `combineReducers`. It generates the error below. Probably just a small mistake I'm making. Link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bengrunfeld/1h0t59uf/

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { Constants } from './constants/constants'


const goal = (state = 0, action) => {
  (action.type === Constants.ADD) ?
    state + action.payload:
    state
}

const target = (state = 0, action) => {
  (action.type === Constants.REMOVE)?
    state - action.payload:
    state
}

const reducer = combineReducers({
  goal,
  target
})

const state = 10

const newState = reducer(state, {
  type: Constants.REMOVE,
  payload: 5
})

render(
  <div>
    <p>{newState}</p>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('main')
)
```

**Error Message**

```
main.bundle.js:28054 Uncaught Error: Reducer "goal" returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined.
    at http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:28054:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at assertReducerSanity (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:28049:25)
    at combineReducers (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:28104:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:13236:42)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:31673:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:20:30)
    at module.exports (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:66:18)
    at http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:69:10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const Constants = {
  REMOVE: "REMOVE",
  ADD: "ADD"
}

const goal = (state = 5, action) => {
  return (action.type === Constants.ADD) ?
    state + action.payload:
    state
}

const target = (state = 5, action) => {
  return (action.type === Constants.REMOVE)?
    state - action.payload:
    state
}

const reducer = Redux.combineReducers({
  goal,
  target
})

const state = {goal: 10, target:5}

const newState = reducer(state, {
  type: Constants.REMOVE,
  payload: 5
})

console.log(newState);

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <p>{newState.goal}</p>
    <p>{newState.target}</p>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('main')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.6.0/redux.min.js"></script>


<div id="main"></div>
```

1. You need to define an initial state for each of your reducers.
2. Also you should return a state from your reducer.

Comment: Your answer works, but receiving the following warning: `The previous state received by the reducer has unexpected type of "Number". Expected argument to be an object with the following keys: "goal", "target"
warning @ redux.js:376`

Comment: You have initialized your state as `state = 10` whereas it should be object like this `{goal: 10, target: 10}` .`goal` reducer will be passed only `state.goal` as state and `target` reducer will be passed only `stat.target` as state.

Answer (score 1):

You need to let Redux know what the initial state is going to be.

Either in the reducers themselves (note es6 default argument)

Edit: I just noticed you did not return anything

```
const goal = (state = 0, action) => {
  return (action.type === Constants.ADD) ?
    state + action.payload:
    state
}

const target = (state = 0, action) => {
  return (action.type === Constants.REMOVE)?
    state - action.payload:
    state
}
```

Or in the second argument of `CreateStore`

Here is some comprehensive documentation on that:
http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/InitializingState.html

Comment: I did that (also updated the question with new code) but I'm still receiving the same error. Here is a link to a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bengrunfeld/1h0t59uf/